# How do I get the length of a string field?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

For a string field, is there a way to get the defined length of the field? For example say I allow a maximum of 10 chars, can I get that in apex?

I am not asking how to get the length of a string (i.e. `str.length()`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for [`DescribeFieldResult.getLength()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getLength):

> For string fields, returns the maximum size of the field in Unicode
>   characters (not bytes).

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.AccountNumber.getDescribe();
Integer lengthOfField = F.getLength();
```

Answer (score 15):

This is pretty straightforward in both Apex and Visualforce using describes:

**Apex:**

```
Integer len = SObjectType.Object__c.Fields.Field__c.Length;
```

**Visualforce:**

```
{!$ObjectType.Object__c.Fields.Field__c.Length}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
integer fieldLength = Schema.SObjectType.CustObj__c.fields.CustField__c.getLength();
```

for more [info](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/03/find-length-of-salesforce-field-in-apex.html)